# 2d libgdx: runtime level generation

Tags: libgdx

I have encountered a problem during my first game development:
I thought of a `Array<Ground> groundArray` that does `groundArray.add` when a new ground will appear on the screen, and removes oldest ground when it will no longer be seen, if player only moves to the right, like in flappy bird.

[image]

The perfect structure would be a queue for such a mechanic, but libgdx doesnt have one. Using libgdx's Array is not intuitive too - i have to reverse the order of elements. It has a method `pop()` that removes the last element, but no such method to use on the first element.

What are my options here?

- extend Array class and add something?
- writing my own queue-like class?

**UPDATE 18/8/2014**

i actually found a way to do it with the default Array:

```
private void checkGround() {
    for (Ground ground : groundArray){
        if (ground.x  + 500 < camera.position.x){
            groundArray.removeValue(ground, true);
        }
    }

    if (groundArray.peek().x < camera.position.x + 500){
        groundArray.add(new Ground(groundX, -150));
        groundX +=50; //my ground texture is 50 pixels wide
    }
}
```

Only question left now - **will it affect performance** when there will be 10000 empty elements before the 10 actual ground elements? In my render method i use:

```
for (Ground ground : groundArray){
        batch.draw(ground.getTextureRegion(), ground.x, ground.y);
    }
```

If yes - i will have to make a re-sort method that shifts all the grounds to the beginning of the array.

Will doing so improve this?:

```
for (Ground ground : groundArray){
        if (ground != null) {
            batch.draw(ground.getTextureRegion(), ground.x, ground.y);
        }
    }
```

After checking apparently the array size doesnt boost , it size is always equals the number of actual ground objects in it, but i thought that it will count also the null values that were ground objects before. But then surely there would be nullpointers when i tried to draw those null's, so the problem looks fully **resolved**.

Comment: [These notes](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/queue/array/types.html) explain how to implement a queue from an array. A linked list would work here too, as adding or removing from its ends is a cheap operation.

Comment: Use a doubly linked list like Anko suggests if available, it is fine for a small number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array (or regular java [] array!) (`Ground[] grounds = initialize all;`) with index that points to the first visible Ground in that array (`int first = 0;`). Keep some counter (`float x = 0;`) which will hold progress to the next index.

```
void update(float delta) {
  x += delta * speed;
  if(x > groundWidth){
    x -= groundWidth;
    grounds[first].generateNew();
    first = (first + 1) % grounds.length;
  }
}

void render(){
  float renderX = -x;
  int tile = first;
  for(int i = 0; i < grounds.length; i++){ //Code in this loop just needs to be called grounds.length times
    grounds[tile].renderAtX(renderX);
    tile = (tile + 1) % grounds.length;
    renderX += groundWidth;
  }
}
```

Something like that.